# Rigging up a machine with moving objects and constraints? Would rigid body sim work for this?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to reproduce [this](https://youtu.be/NnoLrylLqnM) in blender. I have the 3D models for the all the parts. I even tried using rigid body sims to try to achieve the desired end goal with some partial success. The animation is jittery and buggy though, I was wondering if there's a better way to do that. I'm only trying with 2 sliders to begin with. Attached below is a pic of what I am working with.
[image]